# How to turn rvest output into table

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, tabular

Brand new to **R**, so I'll try my best to explain this.
I've been playing with data scraping using the "rvest" package. In this example, I'm scraping US state populations from a table on Wikipedia. The code I used is:

```
library(rvest)
statepop = read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_and_territories_by_population")
forecasthtml = html_nodes(statepop, "td")
forecasttext = html_text(forecasthtml)
forecasttext
```

The resulting output was as follows:

```
[2] "7000100000000000000♠1"                                        
[3] " California"                                                  
[4] "39,250,017"                                                   
[5] "37,254,503"                                                   
[6] "7001530000000000000♠53"                                       
[7] "738,581"                                                      
[8] "702,905"                                                      
[9] "12.15%"                                                       
[10] "7000200000000000000♠2"                                        
[11] "7000200000000000000♠2"                                        
[12] " Texas"                                                       
[13] "27,862,596"                                                   
[14] "25,146,105"                                                   
[15] "7001360000000000000♠36"                                       
[16] "763,031"                                                      
[17] "698,487"                                                      
[18] "8.62%"
```

How can I turn these strings of text into a table that is set up similar to the way it is presented on the original Wikipedia page (with columns, rows, etc)?

Comment: use `html_table()` instead of `html_text()`

Answer (score 2):

Try using rvest's html_table function.
Note there are five tables on the page thus you will need to specify which table you would like to parse.

```
library(rvest)

statepop = read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_and_territories_by_population")
#find all of the tables on the page
tables<-html_nodes(statepop, "table") 
#convert the first table into a dataframe
table1<-html_table(tables[1])
```